# Ubuntu won't allow to use "/" symbol

Tags: filesystem

I'm trying to rename directory and I need to use "/" symbol but ubuntu won't allow it. Is where any way to "cheat" ubuntu into allowing me to use it?

Comment: Please explain why you think you need a `/` symbol. (in fact the answer from Venge already try to explain this, but it's better if you explain it directly)

Answer (score 21):

*You probably don't actually want to do this*. As other people have said, `/` is the directory name separator (i.e., it separates directory names in a path). So if you think that you actually want `/` in a directory name because something is telling you to do it, you're probably misreading the instructions and/or the instructions are wrong. All the answers telling you how to 'fake' it are telling you how to do something you don't want to do, and won't help you anyway: even though a character might look like a forward slash, your OS won't treat it as one for the same reason that it treats 1 and l and I differently.

As 3Doubloons said in a comment, if documentation mentions a folder named `mods/`, what it *actually* means is a folder named `mods`. The fact that it's not finding it is an entirely separate issue.

Comment: Nice answer, you focused on the root of the problem (the other answers just explain how to insert useless lookalike characters). I think you can emphasise that a path ending with `/` does not mean that `/` is required but is used to remove ambiguity about the nature of the path. `mods` can be a file or a directory, `mods/` can only be a directory.

Comment: +1 If we want to be charitable, we can suppose the absent-minded commentators (myself included!) assumed that the OP had already tried to use a plain `mods` directory. Perhaps @user88114 can confirm that.

Answer (score 9):

The / is a reserved character to indicate directories. A block for this is even included in our kernel. More details on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename). You can use another char that -looks- like a / though. From comments in the link:

> There are plenty of other suitable candidates: ⁄ is U+2044 FRACTION SLASH; ∕ is U+2215 DIVISION SLASH; ⧸ is U+29F8 BIG SOLIDUS; ／ is U+FF0F  FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS, and ╱ is U+2571 is BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL UPPER RIGHT TO LOWER LEFT. All would work admirably!

Comment: Yea, the problem is that directory should come with symbol "/" in it's back. So I need a folder "mods/", but then I exctract file which was created in windows I only get name "mods" without "/" at he back. And modding tool is searching for folder named "mods/" but of course it cannot find it. Man, I guess you understand it :)

Comment: I guess I will not be able to play faster than light with mods :(

Comment: Na, It is java crap

Comment: sorry you got a serious problem then. out of my league :X I'll give you an upvote for an interesting q ;-)

Comment: @user88114 Given your comments I suppose you are trying to use Slipstream Mod Manager. That project is open source and hosted in GitHub, and so I suggest you send the devs a bug report: https://github.com/Vhati/Slipstream-Mod-Manager/issues

Comment: @user88114: Are you sure the program needs a folder literally named `mods/`? Usually, the notation `<name>/` simply indicates "a folder named `<name>`, especially in multi-platform projects

Answer (score 2):

No. `/` is directory separator, like `\` and `/` in Windows.

However, if you really want to use `/`, you can use similar characters. In my opinion, U+29F8 (BIG SOLIDUS) looks like a slash, and you can copy it from here. You can also modify the file system directly, but this is not recommended, and probably would confuse operating system a lot, because it would introduce ambiguities (is `/bin/bash` the file in current directory, or path to standard interpreter?).

```
⧸
```

The best way however is avoiding `/` in file names. There are other characters you can use. For example, you can write `&` instead of `/` in certain cases (`files/directories` vs `files&directories`). This will make things less confusing.

Comment: Yea, I thought I was f****d. This is that happens, when windows people write programs for linux :)

Comment: @user88114: [You can't use a `/` in a folder name on Windows, either.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `/` in a folder's name! There's no way Linux could make the difference between a subfolder in folder and single folder.

Read more:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names